# Matching Words With or Without Hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm basically trying to match words in a string that may or may not contain hyphens.
For instance, in the strings below:

```
let firstStr = "filter-table";
let secondStr = "filter-second-table";
```

"filter-" is a required keyword, and so, I'd want to match the words containing "filter-" followed by any character/word (hyphenated or not).

Using the following:

```
secondStr.match(/filter-\w+/);
```

"firstStr" matches correctly but not "secondStr". "secondStr" only matches "filter-second" and not the hyphenated word after - "filter-second-**table**".

I'd want to be able to match any potential hyphenated word as in "second-table".

Answer (score 1):

Make a `group` that can be matched multiple times like this: `/filter(-\w+)+/`

```js
myTest("filter-table");
myTest("filter-second-table");
myTest("filter-awesome-second-table");


function myTest(string){
  let matches = string.match(/filter(-\w+)+/)
  console.log(string, matches ? "matches!" : "doesn't match")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Richard Henage. It works. That's what I needed . I think my problems stems from `grouping`. Sadly I need "reputation" (whatever that means) to upvote your answer.